# Parallelizing MATLAB code

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

Hello I want to use parallelize my MATLAB code to run High computing server. It is code to make image database for Deep learning. To parallelize the code I found the I have to for parfor loop. But I used that with the first loop or with the second loop it shows me error parfor cannot be run due to the variable imdb and image_counter. Anyone please help me to change the code to work with parfor

```
for i = 1:length(cur_images)
            X = sprintf('image Numb: %d ',i);
            disp(X)
        cur_image = load(cur_images{i,:});
        cur_image=(cur_image.Image.crop);


        %----------------------------------------------

        cur_image = imresize(cur_image, image_size);


        if(rgb < 1)
            imdb.images.data(:,:,1,image_counter) = cur_image;
        else
            imdb.images.data(:,:,1,image_counter) = cur_image(:,:,1); 
            imdb.images.data(:,:,2,image_counter) = cur_image(:,:,2);
            imdb.images.data(:,:,3,image_counter) = cur_image(:,:,3); 
            imdb.images.data(:,:,4,image_counter) = cur_image(:,:,4); 
            imdb.images.data(:,:,5,image_counter) = cur_image(:,:,5); 
            imdb.images.data(:,:,6,image_counter) = cur_image(:,:,6); 
            imdb.images.data(:,:,7,image_counter) = cur_image(:,:,7); 
            imdb.images.data(:,:,8,image_counter) = cur_image(:,:,8); 
            imdb.images.data(:,:,9,image_counter) = cur_image(:,:,9); 
            imdb.images.data(:,:,10,image_counter) = cur_image(:,:,10);

        end


        imdb.images.set(     1,image_counter) = set;             
        image_counter = image_counter + 1;
    end
```

Comment: You just need a tutorial on what you can and can not do in parallel

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is that you can't assign to fields of a structure inside `parfor` in the way that you're trying to do. Also, your outputs need to be indexed by the loop variable to qualify as ["sliced"](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variable.html) - i.e. don't use `image_counter`. Putting this together, you need something more like:

```
% Make a numeric array to store the output.
data_out = zeros([image_size, 10, length(cur_images)]);

parfor i = 1:length(cur_images)
    cur_image = load(cur_images{i, :});
    cur_image=(cur_image.Image.crop);
    cur_image = imresize(cur_image, image_size);

    % Now, assign into 'data_out'. A little care needed
    % here.
    if rgb < 1
        data_tmp = zeros([image_size, 10]);
        data_tmp(:, :, 1) = cur_image;
    else
        data_tmp = cur_image;
    end
    data_out(:, :, :, i) = data_tmp;
end
imdb.images.data = data_out;
```

Comment: after loading the size of `cur_image` is `250x250x10`. The data should be store in `imdb.images.data` like (250x250x10x1) for the first image and (250x250x10x2) for the second image. `data_out(:, :, :, i) = data_tmp;` and `imdb.images.data = data_out;` will act like same?

Comment: There is one more thing is this `parfor` loop is working another `for` loop for no of sets. There are 3 sets and for each set this `parfor` is running. The size of first set is  `data_out`  `28x28x61x11028`. The size of second and third set is  `data_out`  `28x28x61x2048`. How can I concatenate it is loop of set?